# Performance measures in Predictive models

Tags: r, weka

I developed predictive models  and I reported G-mean ,F-measure, Sensitivity, and Specificity  which are very low. i wonder if anyone has a reference for the threshold of these measures ? I want to report that model is not good enough however I cant find anything in the literature?
 Thank yo so much and I really appreciate it in advance.
Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

have you used `confusionMatrix` in the `caret` package?

If you use train and test sets it will report the accuracy and the no-information-rate, the former having to be larger than the former for the model to have any predictive value.

eg:

```
          Reference
Prediction  T   F
       T   39  24
       F   24  52

               Accuracy : 0.6547          
                 95% CI : (0.5694, 0.7332)
    No Information Rate : 0.5468          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.006344
```

Comment: i used WEKA, and for the research related purposes I have to report G-mean , F-measure , Sn and Sp. However I can't find any threshold for these for so that I can accept or reject the model